# How to Display SAS date internal value

Tags: date, sas

How can I display the internal date value of a date variable in sas?

I have it currently formatted as a date in the format ddmmyy10. and I would like to display the internal date value.

I initially thought of using the datediff function to get the difference from my date and January 1st 1960 but was wondering if there were a simpler way.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set it as the numeric format `8.`

```
/* Example data */
data have;
    date = '02MAY2022'd;
    
    format date date9.;
run;

/* Change the format of date in the dataset 'have' */
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify have;
        format date 8.;
quit;
```

Output:

```
date
22767
```

Or, in Enterprise Guide, change the format through the GUI:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different format.  Since recent dates are in the tens of thousands of days since 1/1/1960 the COMMA format would work well.

```
proc print data=have ;
   format date comma8. ;
run;
```

Or remove the format completely and let SAS use its default display method for the numbers.

```
proc print data=have ;
   format date ;
run;
```